# Формирование двух треугольников

Tags: html, css

У меня есть два дива, которые заливаются разным цветом. Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы они формировались в один прамоугольник как на скринах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов как можно сделать такой "эффект"

```css
#wrap {
  position: relative;  
  width: 100px;
}

#triangle-topleft {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 100px solid blue; 
 border-right: 100px solid transparent;  
  position: absolute;
}

#triangle-bottomright {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 100px solid yellow; 
 border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
  <div id="triangle-bottomright"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

если вот такая структура

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

то предлагаю вот такие стили

```css
.main {
  position: relative
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 100px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}
.div1 {
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  border-right-color: gray;
}
.div2 {
  border-top-color: tomato;
  border-left-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

*** пардон, в оформлении ещё не силён